# TikZ and compatibility of PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, incompatibility

Reading several posts I understand that TikZ does not support the newer PGF library.

1. How do I downgrade PGF to the last supported version?
2. Are packages other than TikZ become non-compatible by this downgrade?
3. I'm using TikZ for flowcharts. Is there a package other than TikZ that enables flowcharts but does not require downgrade of anything?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Could you explain what you mean? Maybe link to one of the posts you mention? TiKZ is built on top of PGF and they get upgraded or not together, as far as I know. (Maybe not if you install stuff from a development branch or something but if you are using any regular release.) Maybe I'm wrong about this but right now I don't really understand what you are asking. I used TiKZ earlier today, I updated my TeX installation yesterday from the 2014 repos and I have never downgraded PGF!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you link to one or more of those posts? I'm not sure what you mean when you say "TikZ does not support the newer PGF library." Or, you can provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the incompatibility.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can provide examples of newer PGF libraries that TikZ does not support. As said by others, it sounds really strange.

Answer (score 6):

TikZ is a frontend for PGF, or better, a compilation of higher level access commands for the lower level PGF macros.

However this distinction is an abstraction. They are always shipped together and they come from the same author. What you have been reading was probably the incompatibility of the old TikZ code with the new TikZ version (v2.10 as opposed to v3.00). Not only that but also `pgfkeys`,`pgffor` and `pgfmath` come with the same bundle.

It is, up to v3.00, not possible that TikZ does not support PGF. Notice that TikZ comes **with** PGF bundle. So there is no separate shipment of these. Although have different names, they are practically the same thing.

Having said that, I like the possibility if they were separate entities. But it would be a great mess to maintain it.